# FFmpeg segmentation for html mediasource video audio async

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, synchronization, video-streaming

I'm a new questioner, I never had to ask anything here, but I feel a bit clueless about this thing as I never worked with it before.

I would like to build my own live video stream and a new video player for it.

My idea is that with the help of FFmpeg I'm doing live video segmentations where the segments have uniform lengths. I'm constantly writing these in a list file, handling them with an HTML Media Source extension.

The problem is with the sync of audio and video. Either the video gets delayed over time or the audio comes faster than it should, I'm not sure. If I refresh the page/scroll through the video, everything resets, but as time goes on, the sync gets messed up again.
I have no idea what could cause this. I tried to search through many forum posts, but I did not find any solution for it.

I don't want to use HLS or DASH.

> OS: Win10 Browser: Chrome 98.0.4758.102

This is my FFmpeg command:

```
Ffmpeg Command (version 2022-02-24-git-8ef03c2ff1-full_build-www.gyan.dev):
ffmpeg -re -i input.mkv -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1280:720 -c:a copy -sample_rate 44100 -segment_time 2 -r 30 -g 1 -sc_threshold 0 -force_key_frames ""expr:gte(t,n_forced*1)"" -flags +cgop+low_delay -f segment -segment_format_options movflags=+empty_moov+omit_tfhd_offset+frag_keyframe+default_base_moof+isml -segment_list_type ext -segment_list {segment_file_dir} output_%d.mp4
```

HTML Source:

```
<video muted controls></video>

<script>
    segments = [];
    last_segment = 0;
    mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64000d,mp4a.40.2"';
    timestampOffset = 0;
    video = document.querySelector('video');
    mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    sourceBuffer = null;
    segment_process = false;
    
    
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(){
        sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
        sourceBuffer.mode = 'segments';
        
        // Initialization
        const init_xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        init_xhr.open('get', 'init.mp4');
        init_xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        init_xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        init_xhr.send();
        init_xhr.onload = function(){
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(init_xhr.response);
            sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', event = function(){
                sourceBuffer.removeEventListener('updateend', event);
                sourceBuffer.timestampOffset = 0;
                sourceBuffer.remove(0,1);
                
                manifestInitialization(function(){
                    if (segments.length > 0 && segment_process == false){
                        segments = segments.slice(-1);
                        segmentProccess();
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    }.bind(mediaSource));
    
    
    setInterval(function(){
        manifestInitialization(function(){
            if (segments.length > 0 && segment_process == false){
                segmentProccess();
            }
        });
    },500);
    
    
    // Manifest Initialization
    function manifestInitialization(callback){
        const manifest_xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        manifest_xhr.open('get', 'ehls/manifest');
        manifest_xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        manifest_xhr.responseType = 'text';
        manifest_xhr.send();
        
        manifest_xhr.onload = function(e){
            lines = manifest_xhr.responseText.split(/\r?\n/);
            lines.forEach(function(line){
                line = line.split(';');
                const segment = {id: Number(line[0]), file: line[1], duration: Number(line[2]), type: Number(line[3])};
                if (!objectInArray(segment, segments) && segment.id > last_segment){
                    segments.push(segment);
                    last_segment = segment.id;
                }
            });
            callback();
        };
    };
    
    
    // Segment Load
    function segmentProccess(){
        segment_process = true;
        segment = segments.shift();
        const segment_xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        segment_xhr.open('get', 'ehls/' + segment.file);
        segment_xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        segment_xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        segment_xhr.send();
        segment_xhr.onload = function(){
            timestampOffset += segment.duration;
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(segment_xhr.response);
            sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', event = function(){
                sourceBuffer.removeEventListener('updateend', event);
                    sourceBuffer.timestampOffset = timestampOffset;
                    video.oncanplay = function(){
                        video.play();
                    };
                    if (segments.length > 0){
                        segmentProccess();
                        }
                    else{
                        segment_process = false;
                        }
            });
        };
    };
    
    
    // Object in array
    function objectInArray(sObj, array){
        returnV = false;
        array.forEach(function(aObj){
            if (JSON.stringify(sObj) == JSON.stringify(aObj)){
                returnV = true;
            }
        });
        return returnV;
    };
    
</script>
```

Some people in forums mentioned *chrome://media-internals/*, using that I also noticed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpqqY.jpg).

Did anyone work with this before? Do you guys have any idea how could I deal with this sync problem?

Thank you for your answers in advance!